# Too many arguments in Brent function call

Tags: python, scipy

My code:

```
class ImpliedVol:

    def __init__(self, flag, mkt_price, spot_price, strike, time_to_maturity,
                 lower_bound, upper_bound, risk_free_rate=0, maxiter=1000, 
                 method='f'):

        self.flag = flag
        self.mkt_price = mkt_price
        self.S = spot_price
        self.K = strike
        self.T = time_to_maturity
        self.r = risk_free_rate
        self.a = lower_bound
        self.b = upper_bound
        self.n = maxiter
        self.method = method

    def func(self, vol):

        p = Pricer(self.flag, self.S, self.K, self.T, vol, self.r, self.method)

        return p.get_price() - self.mkt_price

    def get(self):

        implied_vol = brentq(self.func, self.a, self.b, self.n)

        return implied_vol
```

Creating an instance of the class with certain parameters works fine, also calling the method `func` works flawlessly as required:

```
obj.func(0.54)
Out[11]:
4.0457814868958174e-05
```

But calling the method `get` on my instance returns the following error:

```
/Users/~/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py in brentq(f, a, b, args, xtol, rtol, maxiter, full_output, disp)
    436     if rtol < _rtol:
    437         raise ValueError("rtol too small (%g < %g)" % (rtol, _rtol))
--> 438     r = _zeros._brentq(f,a,b,xtol,rtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp)
    439     return results_c(full_output, r)
    440 

TypeError: func() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

you are defining: `self.n = maxiter` and calling `brentq` with that as the 4th arg.  However, the signature for brentq is: `scipy.optimize.brentq(f, a, b, args=(), xtol=1e-12, rtol=4.4408920985006262e-16, maxiter=100, full_output=False, disp=True)`

so give it the required positional args (`f`, `a`, `b`), and pass `maxiter` as a keyword arg.  Like this:

```
brentq(self.func, self.a, self.b, maxiter=self.n)
```

(also, do yourself a favor and don't use those one-letter variable names)